# PCIe 4.0 single lane frequency range

Tags: frequency, pcie

I'm looking for a connector for PCIe 4.0 testing (not a standard PCIe connector), but I'm not seeing frequency range values for PCIe, so I'm not sure what connector specs I need. Is there a good rule of thumb to use (twice the unidirectional bandwidth?)?

Comment: be specific, what is that you are testing when you mean PCIe 4.0 testing any card data..

Comment: It's a midbus probe for probing embedded bus signals. My concern is being electrically compliant.